# Sudoku crashes when 'about' button is clicked

Tags: android

Hi I am new to android and I have been trying to do a simple sudoku application.
I am facing a problem now,whenever i click the "about" button the applocation  tends to stop and takes me back to my menu screen.
Can anyone suggest what is the problem for crash??

Below here is my code:

Sudoku.java

```
public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sudoku);
    View continueButton=findViewById(R.id.button1);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View newButton=findViewById(R.id.button2);
    newButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View aboutButton=findViewById(R.id.button3);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    View exitButton=findViewById(R.id.button4);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

        public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button3:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            finish();
            break;

            }
          }
        @Override
           public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
              super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
              MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
              inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
              return true;
           }

 }
```

About.java

```
public class About extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
}
```

about.xml:

```
public class About extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
}
}
```

string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">Sudoku</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Application Sudoku</string>
<string name="continue_label">Continue</string>
<string name="new_game_label">New Game</string>
<string name="about_label">About</string>
<string name="exit_label">Exit</string>
<string name="about_title">About Android Sudoku</string>
<string name="about_text">\Sudoku is a logic-based number placement puzzle.
```

Starting with a partially completed 9x9 grid, the
objective is to fill the grid so that each
row, each column, and each of the 3x3 boxes
(also called *blocks*) contains the digits
1 to 9 exactly once..

activity_sudoku.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/background"
tools:context=".Sudoku" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/continue_label"
    android:textStyle="italic"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    />


</TableRow>
<TableRow >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/about_label"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/exit_label"
         />

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Sudoku Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.example.sudoku"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="org.example.sudoku.Sudoku"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="org.example.sudoku.About"
        android:label="@string/about_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace of your crash

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the intent-filter to the manifest.xml. I faced this problem a lot during starting Android prog. Add it such as:

```
<activity
    android:name="org.example.sudoku.Sudoku"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="org.example.sudoku.About"
    android:label="@string/about_title"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="org.example.sudoku.About" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Later in the Sudoku.java update this part:

```
case R.id.button3:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
```

Update the above as:

```
case R.id.button3:
        startActivity(new Intent("org.example.sudoku.About"));
        break;
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
case R.id.button3:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
```

you put getApplicationContext() or Sudoku.this instead of only this.
because sometime this not refer as a context.

you also use following code against switch()...case statement.

```
public void onClick(View v){

    if(v == aboutButton)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
        finish();
```

}